# can't work url rewrite when a space occured in a value

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

My URL rewrite is not working when I pass the value including space (say New Delhi)
 See my code

```
RewriteRule top-indian-cities-states-(\d+)/(.*)/ top-indian-cities-states.php?id=$1&top=$2
```

When the second parameters become New Delhi it's not working

```
mydomain/top-indian-cities-states-1/New-delhi-Hotel
```

I have given the variable as

```
$name="New Delhi";
$displayName=trim($name." Hotel");
        $urlVal=str_replace(" ","-",$displayName);
<li><a href="top-indian-cities-states-1/<?=$urlVal?> /"><?=$name?> Hotel</a></li>
```

Also when i request the second parameter  i got the value twise
ie

```
echo $_REQUEST['id']; Results in `1` it's correct 

echo $_REQUEST['top'];  Results in `Kerala-Hotel/Kerala-Hotel`  is it correct . i need to get the value only one .
```

Does any one have an idea?

Please Replay

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, you specified a trailing slash after the city name, but you didn't have it in your example (spaces are not allowed).

2 solutions:

1. Add the trailing slash to the regex:

   ```
   RewriteRule top-indian-cities-states-(\d+)/(.*)/? top-indian-cities-states.php?id=$1&top=$2
   ```
2. Add the trailing slash to your variable

   ```
   $urlVal=str_replace(" ","-",$displayName);
   $urlVal=. "/";
   ```

   and drop the slash in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$urlVal=trim(str_replace(" ","-",$displayName));

<li><a href="top-indian-cities-states-1/<?=$urlVal?>/"><?=$name?> Hotel</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Rewriterule like this

```
RewriteRule top-indian-cities-states-(\d+)/(.*)$ top-indian-cities-states.php?id=$1&top=$2


<li><a href="top-indian-cities-states-1/<?=$urlVal?> /"
```

Also remove the / in the above line before double quotes. Give it as

```
<li><a href="top-indian-cities-states-1/<?=$urlVal?>"
```